# What is the way convert XML to Map in Java in specific format?

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have the  XML file in following format. Number of tags and nested hierarchy are randomly. I'm new in Java, so code example will be more than appreciate

```
<a>0
    <b>1
        <c>2
            <d>3
                <e>4</e>
            </d>
            <d>5
                <e>6</e>
                <e>7</e>
                <e>8</e>
            </d>
            <d>9
                <e>10</e>
            </d>
        </c>
    </b>
    <b>11
        <c>12
            <d>13
                <e>14</e>
            </d>
        </c>
        <c>14
            <d>15
                <e>16</e>
            </d>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

I would like to parse it to get the next data sets:

```
0,1,2,3,4
0,1,2,5,6
0,1,2,5,7
0,1,2,5,8
0,1,2,9,10
0,11,12,13,14
0,11,14,15,16
```

In other words - each `a,b,c,d,e` nested combination.

Comment: When you visit the tree (recursively), you can collected the already seen values in a `Stack` (for example `LinkedList`). When you reach a leaf, print the list and `pop` the stack.

Comment: You should rephrase your question so that its not asking for the "best way to do X" since its usually an opinion-based answer. Your question will be down voted and possibly closed.

Comment: I would recommend to use JAXBContext to parse XML into Map<String, Object>. Then build your array from the map.

Comment: Look for Depth-first search in trees.

Comment: @Dmitry JAXB won't work here so easy.

Comment: @lexicore why? I use it all the time. If you do not know the format of the file, simple use Map<String, Object>. I will gyve an example as an answer

Comment: @Dmitry I'd like to stress "so easy" in my comment. You'll have to deal with a mixed content and recursive structure here. Not impossible, but I personally would have to scartch my head. I'd love to see your answer showing how to use JAXB for this structure. ps. The question has a good probability of being closed for the "lack of own effort".

Comment: @lexicore yes, you right. I have tried my method and it have failed on this xml. Unfortunately, JABX will not be able to marshal something like that: <a>0<b>1</b></a>. It should be <a><data>0</data><b><data>1</data></b></a> to make it work